# lyx export fails due to ubuntu updates. !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file tcrm1000): Font tcrm1000 at 600 not found

Tags: pdftex, lyx, ubuntu

I have removed and re-installed lyx, and added all the fonts I can find.  The document has not changed but now cannot generate output.  With added preamble stuff
\usepackage{ae}
I was able to get dvi output, but the dvi output did not display the figures.

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, LyX Version 2.3.6.

Any suggestions?
Found that only the indent structure causes the fault e.g. the tex file:
%% LyX 2.3.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item xxxx
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
generates the above pdf error.

Anyone now able to help?

Comment: It might be an idea to export the file to latex format and post it here, then we have an better idea as to what exactly you are doing. Additionally, exactly what LaTeX have you installed on your Ubuntu? If it is the texlive from Ubuntu, that is broken info smaller Debian bundles and thus you may be missing a font that you are using.

Comment: all the .lyx docs I tested fail, however their content is a little sensitive so I am not happy to post the full tex.  I will try using a fake doc.